# Inject repositories into service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, service, dependency-injection, repository

I have following;

```
interface IRepository
--interface IRepositoryEF: IRepository
--interface IRepositoryNH: IRepository
----interface ICategoryRepositoryEF: IRepositoryEF
----interface ICategoryRepositoryNH: IRepositoryNH
```

I want to use `CategoryRepositoryEF` and `CategoryRepositoryNH` classes in the service. How can I inject them into CategoryService?

```
CategoryService(IRepository repository)
{

}
```

What is the best practice about this? Could I use a `RepositoryFactory` and inject it into service and then create repositories in the services?

I mean something like following;

```
CategoryService(CategoryRepositoryFactory factory)
{
    var CategoryRepositoryEF = factory.Create("EF");
    var CategoryRepositoryNH = factory.Create("NH");
}
```

Is this good idea? Or I m completely wrong?

Comment: Why does your `CategoryService` need two repositories for the same entity?

Comment: @Steven , in fact, I should use ADO.NET and Entity framework in the same service, CRUD operations with EF and select operations with ADO.NET, this is a business rule... I want to integrate [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522226/ADO-NET-2cplustheplusrightplusway) to my EF repository

Comment: Business rule? I think you mean architectural rule. The business won't care which technology you use (except when you're working for MS of course; they won't let you use Java) :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is a bit off.

the purpose of repository interfaces is to abstract away the data source. the goal is to allow all using classes to fetch information without knowing where the data comes from. But in your case you force the classes to know wether NHibernate or EntityFramework is used. Why?

I also wouldn't have a `IRepository` interface, as you create specific interfaces.

Now the question is rather "How do I map a nhibernate or entity framework repository to one of my interfaces".

That should be done when the application starts. You typically do something like this:

```
container.Register<ICategoryRepostitory, NHCategoryRepository>();
container.Register<IUserRepostitory, EFUserRepository>();
```

If you don't do that you have effectivly coupled the using code with a specific implementation. There is really no need for any interfaces at all then.

**Update**

> Which repository is used if I inject like `CategoryService(ICategoryRepository repository)`?

The repository that you registered in your inversion of control container. My point is that you should not register both implementations but just one of them for every repository.

A simple example would be below.

First manage the repository type with your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RepositoryType" value="NHibernate" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And then do this when you configure your inversion of control container:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RepositoryType"] == "NHibernate"))
{
    _autofac.RegisterType<NHCategoryRepository>.As<ICategoryRepository>();
    _autofac.RegisterType<NHUserRepository>.As<IUserRepository>();
}
else
{
    _autofac.RegisterType<EFCategoryRepository>.As<ICategoryRepository>();
    _autofac.RegisterType<EFUserRepository>.As<IUserRepository>();
}
```

Comment: This answer is absolutely not "off". You're absolutely spot on. Its his design that is causing him problems. His abstractions are leaking. (+1)

Comment: @jgauffin ,sorry I cant explain my problem. May be this examples explain it. I want to integrate this two suggestion, [Example1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522226/ADO-NET-2cplustheplusrightplusway), [Example2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle) Also, first example is your article. I want to integrate your example and other...

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: Funny that you linked my ADO.NET article =) I still do not understand why the services have to know if EF or NH is used?

Comment: how can I use repository in service. If I inject it like this : `CategoryService(IRepository repository){this.repo = repository;}` and `public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories(){return repo.GetAll();//which repo will run?}`

Comment: Inject the repository as I explained and configure the inversion of control container as I explain. Doing so should make everything work as you want. Maybe you should read my IoC article too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386164/Get-injected-into-the-world-of-inverted-dependenci

Comment: I think, I didnt understand service and repository yet and I should read more about this topic :( Now, I m reading your article. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dependency injector as [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) and inject parameter trough contructor

**Your NinjectModule**

```
public class NinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        this.Bind<ICategoryRepositoryEF>().To<CategoryRepositoryEF>();
        this.Bind<ICategoryRepositoryNH >().To<CategoryRepositoryNH>();
        this.Bind<ICategoryService >().To<CategoryService>();
    }
}
```

**Inject dependencies**

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectModule());
var categoryService = kernel.Get<ICategoryService>();
```

This is just an example but take into account that dependencies should be injected on the composition root (entry point) of the application.